# ¿Como ocultar un valor o celda en un ListGrid pero mostrarlo en un GroupSummaryRow?

Tags: java, eclipse, smartgwt

estoy utilizando la libreria **com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid** para crear un ListGrid, el problema en el que me encuentro es en el momento de implementar un GroupSummaryRow necesito borrar o ocultar que el campo se muestre en el ListGrid pero seguir mostrando el valor en el GroupSummaryRow[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna SALDO FINAL solo se debe mostrar en el GroupSummaryRow en lugar de que repita el dato en el ListGrid

Comment: Buenas Roberto, para poder ayudarte con tu respuesta, necesitamos saber de código que estás usando. Y al usar una librería específica, saber si la misma la estás usando apropiadamente. Por favor lee [mre] y agrega el código faltante a la pregunta. (el código que te da el problema).